# Query GraphQL Mutation Schema

Tags: graphql

Is there a way to query the schema of mutations of a graphql server using HTTP?  Or a way to query the entire schema of a graphql server?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure is. The official GraphQL specs outline [the introspection specifics](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Schema-Introspection). An example of fetching the available mutations might look like so ...

```
{
  __schema {
    mutationType {
      fields {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful.

I also found the graphiql plugin really helpful as a GUI way to explore graphql endpoints: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql